# Ionic build issue with admob free plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, build, build.gradle, cordova-admob

Cannot build, After add Admob Free plugin.

multiDexEnabled issue resolved by adding "multiDexEnabled true".

Now, Problem:
Execution failed for task '**:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease**' ......
**duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzalj.class**

[image]

Created a Repo: https://github.com/amin2009/conf102

Comment: I have the same error. I spent 2 days without any luck. You may consider trying the admob plus or admob pro. For me, admob plus requires latest cordova which I cannot install. The admob pro has conflicts with other google map plugin. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ManCoding. 
It delayed my app publishing. 
I decided not to use any ad plugin. For now, I am using ad placeholder. I'll think about displaying real ads in the future.

Comment: can you please provide more details like which ionic, node & cordova versions you are using ?
I have used AdmobFree and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks @MohamadAlAsmar I was working with it long ago. I lost my interest already. I may not continue that coding.

Comment: you can delete the question then, better for the community.